# Sudden rational result from devision in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, division, rational-numbers

When doing the devision in IRB:

```
6/3600
```

the result is always 0.

But in a live Rails application running in WEBrick or Apache/Passenger the same division results in `1/600` value of type `Rational`.

I am getting the same Rational result when doing division in a breakpoint's watch in RubyMine 6.3.3

Both arguments are always Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the `mathn` module. For some reason it's not loaded in your IRB, but it's loaded by something in your server session and probably from a debugging gem in the RubyMine debug session as well.

The behaviour you experienced is documented here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/Numeric.html

You can test this in your IRB session. `6/3600` results in `0`. After you loaded `mathn` with `require 'mathn'` you get another result. It will be `(1/600)` instead.

You can also force each situation, to make your code more robust at this point. If you want a rational result anyway you can do something like `6/3600.to_r` or vice versa if `mathn` is loaded `(6/3600).to_i`. Another way to make a division explicit is to use the method `div()`.

Here a dump of an IRB session, which is a conclusion of the text above.

```
>> 6/3600
0

>> 6/3600.to_r
(1/600)

>> require 'mathn'
true

>> 6/3600
(1/600)

>> (6/3600).to_i
0

>> 6.div(3600)
0
```

This topic is also discussed here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2121

Comment: Thank you for the clue. Mathn really replaces the / division operator for `Fixnum` and `Bignum` classes making it an alias for `quo` method. I found usage of Mathn in `geometry` and `ruby-units` gems. If they are removed from `Gemfile` division works in a normal way.